# Type Task<> exists in both Unity.Tasks and mscorelib (Unity Question)

Tags: visual-studio, firebase, unity-game-engine, namespaces, task

I have run across an infuriating issue. I am using System.Threading.Tasks in my project. I recently imported a new plugin (Google Firebase) which ships with it's own dll (Unity.Tasks). Well, it seems like the geniuses at Google didn't realize that Unity has full support of System.Threading.Tasks and decided to bundle that namespace with their dll. I cannot get rid of Unity.Tasks or it breaks Firebase. I cannot use an extern alias to reference mscorelib or I get errors stating that my code doesn't return a Task<> (when it indeed did before I used the alias). I am at a loss of what I should do here. I would really like to use firebase as it is very easy to implement, but I also need to use Tasks in my project for asynchronous programming. Anybody have any bright ideas?

Note: I am using Unity 2020 beta 2 and .Net 4.0 with the IL2CPP backend. I have tried with .NET 2.0, mono backend, and Unity 2019.x. No success. Any and all help appreciated.

Also: I have indeed checked all the other Stack Overflow answers and none of them will work in my instance. I have tried all of them.

[Here is a screenshot of the error thrown in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrEoq.png)

Comment: Are you able to mark Unity.Tasks.dll to not be autoreferenced in the inspector? Precompiled firebase DLLs will still see it but your code won't.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to to that to be honest. I've never ran into this issue before so I've never had to do it. I have unreferenced Unity.Tasks.dll and Unity threw a shit ton of errors because firebase could not find the dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duplicate task implementation ships in the Firebase SDK for backwards compatibility reasons. If you imported the `dotnet4` folder, it shouldn't be enabled by default but if you've lost the `.meta` files (or the `Library` directory in the case of you not using `.meta` files) or have been manually tweaking your build settings (ex: pulling in the wrong dependencies when writing `.asmdef` files) you may pull in the incorrect ones again.

Check `Assets/Parse/Plugins`

[image: <code>Assets/Parse/Plugins</code> is selected]

Make sure base level `Unity.Tasks` and `Unity.Compat` are disabled (you may delete these if you want).

[image: Select platforms for plugin on <code>Unity.Tasks</code> is unchecked for all platforms]

And make sure that the dlls in the `dotNet45` folder are enabled:

[image: Any Platform selected for Unity.Tasks in <code>Parse/Plugins/dotNet45</code>]

You should be good to go!

A quick aside: you may wonder why we're including `Unity.Tasks` at all. Firebase won't compile against a vanilla task implementation, the `dotNet45` implementation forwards a few functions and makes sure that Firebase can be used without any code rewrites.

Now that I've given you this brief overview, there is one more thing you can do. [Support for the Unity Package Manager](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-sdks-upm) was just released. If you're in a supported version of Unity (2018.4 or newer), you can move Firebase into UPM. Then all of these files will move to the `Library` folder and will hopefully be automatically kept cleaner for you going forward. There are some minor issues (ex: patching a `gradleTemplate.gradle` doesn't quite work last time I checked, which is an optional feature), but it could be overall a cleaner integration (and should be improved over time).

I hope that helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Excellent! I have deleted Firebase completely from my project and installed it with the Package Manager instead. I now am able to use Tasks without compile errors! Thanks a million!

Comment: I should also let you know (I left a comment on your github as well) that Firebase does not work on Android builds in the Unity 2020 beta. I had to downgrade to Unity 2019 stable and the build works. Might want to look into this before Unity 2020 ships to public ;) Love y'alls plugin! Keep up the great work!