# error CS0012: The type 'Task<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Unity.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, dll, reference

I'm unable to build a firebase authentication project, receiving the following error in Unity 2022.1.12f1 (latest version):

Assets\Scripts\FirebaseGoogleLogin.cs(83,13): error CS0012: The type 'Task<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Unity.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The general consensus I'm seeing is that I'm missing a .dll or a preference but i do not know how to fix it. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? here's the full code:

///////

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using Firebase.Auth;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Google;
using System.Net.Http;



public class FirebaseGoogleLogin : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This is requiered for google sign in, the API provided by firebase.
    public string GoogleWebAPI = "156713740158-5h54pcnlng8708rljonv24p9afcrnudt.apps.googleusercontent.com";

    private GoogleSignInConfiguration configuration;

    Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;


    public Text UsernameTxt, UserEmailTxt;

    public Image UserProfilePic;

    public string imageUrl;

    public GameObject LoginScreen, ProfileScreen;


    void Awake()
    {
        // Here I will configure the webAPI key with Google
        configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration
        {
            WebClientId = GoogleWebAPI,
            RequestIdToken = true
        };
    }


    void Start()
    {
        InitFirebase();
    }


    void InitFirebase()
    {
        auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    }

    void GoogleSignInClick()
    {
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestEmail = true;

        GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished);
    }


    void OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
    {
        if(task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Fault");
        }
        else if(task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Login Cancel");
        }
        else
        {
            Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(task.Result.IdToken, null);

            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
            {

                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    DebugLogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    DebugLogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                    return;
                }


                user = auth.CurrentUser;


                UsernameTxt.text=user.DisplayName;
                UserEmailTxt.text=user.Email;

                LoginScreen.SetActive(false);
                ProfileScreen.SetActive(true);

                StartCoroutine(LoadImage(CheckImageUrl(user.PhotoUrl.ToString())));
            });

        }
    }

    private string CheckImageUrl(string url)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            return url;
        }


        return imageUrl;
    }

    IEnumerator LoadImage(string imageUri)
    {


        WWW www = new WWW(imageUri);
        yield return www;


        UserProfilePic.sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is being a bit misleading? Are you trying to make use of `System.Threading.Tasks` ? If so, you could just add a `using System.Threading.Tasks;` at the top of your code file.

Comment: If that doesn't fix your issue, then perhaps this question will guide you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422962/unity3d-the-type-task-exist-in-both-unity-tasks-and-mscorelib

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Task<> exists in both Unity.Tasks and mscorelib (Unity Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897443/type-task-exists-in-both-unity-tasks-and-mscorelib-unity-question)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you added dotnet3 package of firebase. I deleted all Firebase file (Firebase folder and Parse folder) and add Firebase dotnet4 again to get it to work.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).