# error CS0433: The type 'Task<T>' exists in both 'Unity.Tasks, ...' and 'netstandard, V...'

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am a beginner at Unity, went to sleep with no errors, and woke up to find around 30. All the errors are of 'error CS0433' and are occurring in path 'Library\PackageCache'.
These are my Errors:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5sIM.png)

I have tried the following solutions:

1. I deleted all the files in the Library folder after closing my Unity project and then re-opened the project.
2. I tried updating all my Unity packages.
3. I installed the recommended versions of the packages.
4. followed the method provided [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-cs0433-the-type-unitylifecyclemanager-exists-in-both-unityengine-advertisements-editor.916277/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897443/type-task-exists-in-both-unity-tasks-and-mscorelib-unity-question?rq=2)
5. Tried some other solutions I found online, which I realize, were not solutions.

Comment: How did this Unity.Tasks come about?

Comment: I have not used Unity.Tasks in any of my scripts, rather the reference (in console) is being given to package files inside the package cache folder (i.e. UnitySevices.cs, AsyncOperationsBase.cs etc).

Comment: No, they just use `Task`, but one of the packages or plugins has `Unity.Tasks`, you need to find it. If you are using Visual Studio, you can search in the object browser.

Comment: I am using vs code. I searched and it gave 100 results in 49 files. they had these paths in common: Assets/Parse/Plugins/dotNet45/Unity.Tasks.dll (in AssetImportWorker4.log and AssetImportWorker5) and Assets\Parse\Plugins\Unity.Tasks.dll (references given in this path)

Comment: Isn't that the same as the 2nd question you followed?

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I didn't understand what you asked of me and replied as to how I understood what you meant. I searched in the search bar in visual studio code for 'Unity.Tasks' and I told the results as I saw them.